# Angular Material Mat-Menu won't check available space before opening, and cuts off

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

I understand that when mat-menu is triggered it would check if theres enough space to open the menu below (if set to below for that matter) and if not it will open above, and indeed in the example section at the angular material documentation it works. but mine just dosen't seem to work:

[image: whats happening:]

and ideas as to why this would happen?
here's the code:

.html:

```
  <button *ngIf="row.emsf.toString() !== '0' && (isBrowserOnline$ | async) && getOnlineStat()"
                [matMenuTriggerFor]="ptnmenu" mat-mini-fab class="ptn-menu-btn"
                [ngClass]="{'no-margin': showQC | async}"
                (click)="$event.stopImmediatePropagation(); $event.stopPropagation(); $event.preventDefault(); ">
                <mat-icon class="ptn-menu-icn">menu</mat-icon>
              </button>

              <mat-menu #ptnmenu="matMenu" xPosition="before" class="menuptn">
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="getAlsRep(0, row)">Print Report</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="sendMailRep(row)">Send to Hospital</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="sendMailCrew(row)">Message to crew</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="alsAttachments(row)">Attachments</button>
                <button *ngIf="showQcButton" mat-menu-item (click)="openInciLookup(row)">Change Incident #</button>
                <button *ngIf="showQcButton && !row.fromCad" mat-menu-item (click)="openChangeCAD(row)">Change CAD
                  #</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="openHistoryModal(row)">ePCR History</button>
                <button mat-menu-item (click)="duplicatePatient(row)">Duplicate Patient</button>
              </mat-menu>
```

Its inside a mat-table row.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes just asking the question helps you find the answer. Apparently I had a style in style.css that was causing it.

```
.mat-menu-panel.menuptn {
  top: -30px !important;
  position: absolute !important;
  right: 30px !important;
}
```

I'll leave it here for future generations.
Cheers!